# InflateException Android

Tags: android, xml

My application stop and I get Binary XML file error on line #0. It`s kinda weird, because I didn't see problem like this with line 0

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.s2s.doupnow, PID: 21011
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.s2s.doupnow/com.s2s.doupnow.UserEarningPayoutPaytm}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2740)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2801)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1548)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6356)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:791)
       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

In the error its referring to this xml page --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_paytm" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="170dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_right" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="9dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/borderfull">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/borderfull">

                <customfonts.MyEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:hint="CARD NUMBER"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:textSize="13dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="18dp"
                android:background="@drawable/borderfull">

                <customfonts.MyEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:hint="CARDHOLDER'S NAME"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <customfonts.MyTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Request Payout"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

            <customfonts.MyTextView
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Back"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Where is the problem, not getting any idea to debug, kindly help to get out of this problem.

Full stack trace --

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.s2s.doupnow, PID: 21011
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.s2s.doupnow/com.s2s.doupnow.UserEarningPayoutPaytm}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2740)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2801)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1548)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6356)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:791)
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:812)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
      at com.s2s.doupnow.UserEarningPayoutPaytm.onCreate(UserEarningPayoutPaytm.java:16)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6861)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2801)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1548)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6356)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:791)
   Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=33; index=1982
      at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
      at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
      at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:1214)
      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:204)
      at android.content.res.MiuiTypedArray.getString(MiuiTypedArray.java:32)
      at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1100)
      at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:704)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:76)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:72)
      at customfonts.MyTextView.<init>(MyTextView.java:0)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:812) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
      at com.s2s.doupnow.UserEarningPayoutPaytm.onCreate(UserEarningPayoutPaytm.java:16) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6861) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2801) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1548) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6356) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:791) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: try to click "Ctrl+right click on mouse" on `customfonts.MyTextView` , it will navigate to java class  `MyTextView` or not ? one of you view tag class not found in layout.